# Cardio app: clear timer for interval located in function scope

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Here is Cardio app on CodePen.
http://codepen.io/Mahmoud-Zakaria/pen/vxWzxW?editors=1010
When I want to stop the cardio by stop btn and clear its interval which its refernce in function scope, It doesn't stop/clear.

```
 (function() {

  //States
  let i = 5;
  let play = true;

  //DOM
  let cardioSec = document.getElementById('cardio-sec');
  let cardioStart = document.getElementById('cardio-start');
  let cardioStop = document.getElementById('cardio-stop');

  //Render
  function render(el) {
    el.innerHTML = i
  };


  //Audio
  let audio = new Audio("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mahmoudZakaria90/myCodePenStuff/master/audio/Bepp-beep.mp3");

  //Setup 
  function setInterVals(times, callback) {
    i = times;
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(i) //RENDER
      render(cardioSec)
      i--;
      if (i < 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        audio.play();
        callback();
      }

    }, 1000)
    return timer;
  }

  function start() {
    setInterVals(5, cardio);
  }

  function cardio() {
    setInterVals(30, rest);
  }

  function rest() {
    setInterVals(15, cardio);
  }

  function stopCardio() {
    clearInterval(setInterVals())
  }

  cardioStart.onclick = start

  cardioStop.onclick = stopCardio

})();
```

Comment: Your `setInterVals` function is returning the interval reference but it isn't getting assigned to anything. Make `timer` a variable outside that function (maybe in your `States` section?)

Comment: Ok but I want to fire it on start btn not initial

Comment: Moving the variable declaration of `timer` outside the function scope doesn't influence the way the assigning works. Just put `let timer = -1;` below `let play = true;` and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes It was my bad actually with a lot of trying to fix it I forgot to put into the stopCardio function this ```clearInterval(setInterVals())```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Done:
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmdLMr?editors=1010

```
The "timer" variable was out of the scope, by declaring it as global, you wont have problems ^^
```

Comment: Yeah Yeah was my bad, fixed it, same issue.
And I want to fire the function on event input, like start btn.

Comment: You Did it! but how I can't find your code your fork code, give me a moment :D

Comment: hhhh yeah found it, like you said put it in global but I don't think it's a good practise because what if we had 'use strict'; ?

Comment: Sorry it works now instead of hoist it in the function scope I make it hoist on the global scope by ```let timer;``` as ```undefined```

Comment: If you prefer the let timer version try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxzgLm?editors=1010